# Can't load and parse xml file on android in c++

Tags: android, c++, xml, cocos2d-x, rapidshare

I'm working on a Cocos2dx C++ project and I am trying to load a XMLfile and parse it with rapidxml.

The Win32 build works great with this code.

```
rapidxml::file<> xmlFile("myxml.xml"); 
xml_document<> doc; // character type defaults to char
doc.parse<0>(xmlFile.data());    // 0 means default parse flags
xml_node<> *main = doc.first_node();  //Get the main node that contains everything
```

This does not work for the Android build. It's most likely because "myxml.xml" can't be found.
So my solution was to load the file in a different way.

So I tried to replace the xmlFile.data() with this. The mobile could now locate and read the data but I was unable to parse it trough rapidxml.

```
const unsigned char* xmldata = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getFileData("myxml.xml", "r", &tmpSize);
```

But then I have no idea how to parse it.

This is another way of getting the data but still no idea how to parse with rapidxml.

```
std::string xmldata2 = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getStringFromFile("myxml.xml");
```

Any ideas how to parse this in rapidxml, or any other suggestions how to solve this?

I'm new to c++ so any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [PugiXML](http://pugixml.org/) and it is relatively simple to use. A file is read as:

```
xml_document* doc = new xml_document;
unsigned char* pBuffer = NULL;
unsigned long bufferSize = 0;

std::string fullPath = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->fullPathFromRelativePath(filename);

pBuffer = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getFileData(fullPath.c_str(), "r", &bufferSize);

if(bufferSize == 0)
{
    CCLog("file failed to open");
    delete doc;
}

xml_parse_result results = doc->load_buffer(pBuffer, bufferSize);
CCLog("filename: %s | result: %s | status: %d",filename, results.description(), results.status);

if(pBuffer)
{
    delete [] pBuffer;
    pBuffer = NULL;
}
xml_node mainNode = doc->child("main");
```

mainNode then has contents of the parsed file.